# Http response fast after removing session

Tags: asp.net, session, iis, session-cookies

I have got a problem with my page loading speed. My solution is an Asp.Net on a Sitecore CMS. When I browse a page the response is very slow, the time depends. After removal of session cookie with EditThisCookie in Chrome and reload of the page, the page is amazingly fast.

Right now the times are (from Fiddler2):

```
**Before session removal:**    
ServerGotRequest:   12:32:34.968
ServerBeginResponse:    12:32:39.569

**After session removal:**
ServerGotRequest:   12:33:22.354
ServerBeginResponse:    12:33:23.300
```

I have replaced the sessionstatemodule with [this](https://github.com/dermeister0/LockFreeSessionState) one to see if there is any difference, but no.

Could anyone help with the problem or just explain me why it behave like this after a session removal?

Answer (score 0):

When you first browse the page sitecore caches the item and so second page load is always faster.

If you enable rendering info by appening ?sc_ri=1 to your url and it will tell you which rendering takes the longest time

Comment: If I do not clear the session cookie from Chrome the page is still slow. I will try your suggestion and keep you informed.